# Unable to find Red Hat Server

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd

Running into a strange problem. I have a local server running Red Hat on a virtual machine (accessed through putty). I'm using this server to work on a website in Django, which I run with:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0: 8080.
```

Now that works just fine, and I can access it through redHatIP:8080. However, I recently downloaded and installed Wordpress, Drupal, and [Mint](http://haveamint.com/). Mint was added to the original site, and I access it through redHatIP/mint. Wordpress and Drupal are completely unrelated to the original site, but are both located in /var/www/html (long with the original site located through my 8080 poty).

I accessed drupal and wordpress through redHatIP/drupal and redhatIP respectively, and it was working just fine until today. For some reason when I go to redHatIP now I receive the following error in my internet browser:

```
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

If I go to redHatIP/drupal I received The requested URL /drupal was not found on this server, to redHatIP/anything I receive The requested URL /anything was not found on this server et cetera. This applies to Mint as well, which I access through redHatIP/mint. However, I can still access the original site through redHatIP:8080, and that works just fine.

I completely removed Django and wordpress, then downloaded them again. I tried having just one of them located in /var/www/html/, but that did nothing. I tried moving them to /var/www/, but that also did nothing.

When I go to my error log messages in /pwd/log/httpd/error_log It has the following message:

```
_default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence.
```

However this was reported the day *before* all this happened, when I had both Django and Wordpress together, and there hasn't been any message since.

I have been unable to fix this on my own, nor have I found a solution on the net. Any ideas? Any other information that would help understand the problem? et cetera?

Comment: There are a lot of details you left out here.  When you say "could not access", what errors are you seeing?  Perhaps you should take a look at your /var/log/httpd/error_log to see if there are any errors?

Comment: The only error messsages in error_log was because I had both wordpress and drupal in html:
    _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence.    
  and sorry for the vagueness, and I worded that -really- poorly. When I go to redHatIP I see the following error message:
   The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at your apache configuration files and see what's changed in there.

Comment: Since it appears your question is related to servers, can you try http://serverfault.com/?

Comment: I've reformatted the question. Can you check if my edits are okay?

Comment: Edits are fine, -but- I actually resolved this awhile ago, and I thought I edited my question to include that. Must not have saved it or something. Will edit it now.

Comment: yeah David, you had it right. a co-worker adjusted the files while he was on vacation without notifying me, for some reason :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else working on the same server remotely made some adjusted to the httpd .conf files while he was on Vacation without notifying me. In var/etc/conf.d all the .conf files had their DocumentRoot set to the Drupal6 folder, instead of the Wordpress folder.